# shadcn dialog does not close on submit button

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using shadcn dialog component, and I changed a bit its default behavior, since the submit button was always working (even if you don't type anything in the fields), which  is not What I wanted.
Now, the submit button does not work (the dialog does not close through the submit button, only through clicking outside dialog/close button).

I have this dialog

```
        <Dialog>
          <DialogTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="outline" className="rounded">
              <AiOutlineUserAdd className="ml-2 h-4 w-4" />
              Add Trainee</Button>
          </DialogTrigger>
          <DialogContent className="sm:max-w-[425px]">
            <DialogHeader>
              <DialogTitle>Add Trainee</DialogTitle>
              <DialogDescription>
                Add the email of your trainee.
              </DialogDescription>
            </DialogHeader>
            <div className="grid gap-4 py-4">
              <div className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4">
                <Label htmlFor="email" className="text-right">
                  Email
                </Label>
                <Input id="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} className="col-span-3 rounded" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <DialogFooter isSubmit={isEmail}>
              <DialogClose asChild>
                <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Save</Button>
              </DialogClose>
            </DialogFooter>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
```

also have this:

```
  const emailCheck = (email: string) => {
    const re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return re.test(email);
  }

  const isEmail = emailCheck(email);
```

I have changed a bit the dialog footer.

```
interface DialogFooterProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  isSubmit?: boolean;
}

const DialogFooter: React.FC<DialogFooterProps> = ({
  className,
  isSubmit,
  ...props
}) => (
  <div
    dir="rtl"
    className={cn(
      'flex flex-col-reverse sm:flex-row sm:justify-center sm:space-x-2',
      className
    )}
    {...props}
  >
    {isSubmit && <DialogPrimitive.Close />}
    {props.children}
    {isSubmit && <DialogPrimitive.Close />}
  </div>
);

DialogFooter.displayName = "DialogFooter"
```

Also, I would like to know how I change the dialog to work with nextJS parallel routing.

Comment: Mentioned `handleSubmit` function definition is not there, please add it.

Answer (score 4):

```
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
...

function Form() {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
...

async function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
...
if (response.ok) {
setOpen(false);
}
...
return (
<Dialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
...

        <DialogFooter>
          <Button type="submit">Save changes</Button>
        </DialogFooter>
      </form>
    </Form>
  </DialogContent>
</Dialog>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)

const { reset } = form;
const { isSubmitting, isSubmitSuccessful } = form.formState;

React.useEffect(() => {
  isSubmitSuccessful && reset()

}, [isSubmitSuccessful, reset])

const onSubmit = () => {
   setOpen(false);
}

<Dialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
```

This is working with Dialog closing and form reset functionality with react-hook-form.

Answer (score 1):

See the first aswer of this issue:

https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/386

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).